# Execution plan for app-level queries

Tags: .net, sql-server

How should I go about optimizing application level sql queries, we have a large system that has sql in at least 30 data access classes, all queries are embedded into *.cs files.

Is there an automated way to get execution plans for all those queries so that we can figure out the missing indexes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is query some DMVs to retrieve a list of all the execution plans that are currently cached.

e.g.

```
SELECT s.[text] AS SqlText,
    qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans p
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (p.plan_handle) s
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan (p.plan_handle) qp
```

This will return each SQL query which has a plan cached at the moment in the database, and the corresponding execution plan XML. For this, you'll need to run through your application and make sure you hit all the areas that execute SQL in order to ensure those statements get cached.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL Server Profiler to record all queries and even include execution plans.
You might use the recorded trace to run the index optimization assistant.